# unable to detect select tag option after width change too 100%

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have set my select tag into width 100%,[image]

If you see at my image, i gonna make select the option tag and append the selection value to div above. the problem now is when i click on the option's TEXT, it will trigger the function and append the text into div. However, when i click on the white space of the option, the select option will highlighted(:selected) but it wont pass the value to div above and dont event go trigger the function.
Here's my script

 HTML

```
   <div>
                       
                        <div>
                            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-dropdown" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                             Plase Select
                            </a>

                        </div>
                        <div class="collapse collapse-content" id="collapseExample">
                            <div class="card card-body">
                                <select name="bt-bank-amt" id="bt-bank-method" size="2">

                                    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                                    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                                    <!-- use button if kennot -->
                                  
                                  </select> </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

MY CSS

```
select {
    background-image: none !important;
    width: 100%;
}
```

MY JS

```
   $("select option").click(function() {
        // alert("a");
        var a = $(this).val();
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find(".btn-dropdown").text('').append(a);
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().removeClass("collapse in").addClass("collapse");
        // alert(a);
    });
```

Comment: Hi can you show that div html as well where you are appending your text ?

Comment: hi @Swati, i had update my html

Comment: Hi tested this but i am not seeing that behavior can you make jsfiddle to show that behaviour ?